# Is it possible to do Robust PCA on Images

Tags: machine-learning, python, pca, image-preprocessing

I have a task to perform outlier detection on a medical image data set (CheXpert), but with more „classical“ techniques (i.e. not use a DL approach like GANs or AEs) and I was wondering whether robust pca could be a possible method? I’ve seen it used on time series but not on images so I was wondering if this was a good approach or what the best practice was and why? If you know of any papers or code on this topic I’d be very grateful. So far I’ve read this [1](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0912.3599.pdf)

Thank you!